# Cannot write into the JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently making a badge system for my discord bot, and I would like to have a command to modify the user badges. I have made the code but it did not edit it.

My code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def modifybadges(ctx, userid, badge):
    try:
        data = get_data()
        for profile in data:
            if profile['discord_id'] == f"{userid}":
                profile = {'discord_id': f"{userid}", 'badges': f"{badge}"}
        await ctx.send(f"Successfully gave user <@{userid}> badge {badge}.")
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"error {e}")
```

```
def set_data(data):
    with open('profiles.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(dumps(data, indent=2))

def profile(badges, discord_id, mode):
    data = get_data()
    if mode == 'create':
        data.append({"discord_id": discord_id, "badges": badges})
    elif mode == 'modify':
        for profile in data:
            if profile['discord_id'] == f"{discord_id}":
                profile = {'discord_id': f"{discord_id}", 'badges': f"{badges}"}
    set_data(data)
```

If you have any ideas on how to fix it, please leave a reply below, thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific. When you say it 'did not edit it', are you referring to when you write to the file: file.write(dumps(data, indent=2))?

Comment: Yes...........................

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('profiles.json', 'w') as file:
     file.write(dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Try this **
*Please provide us a exact error*